# jQuery Mobile - Add more records to a list

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a mobile web app. It is currently using iUI. I've rewritten it jQuery Mobile to try out the functionality. One thing I haven't figured out is how to replace content with Ajax.

I have list of records. I only want to display 5 records at a time. iUI has a feature where you tell the link to "replace-with" and it will replace the link with the data returned by Ajax.

So how do I do this with jquery mobile? I've tried a few jquery calls but I generally get this error and everything stops working:

```
b.height(i + j).data("page") is undefined
[Break On This Error] a.mobile.minScrollBack&&(j=0);d&&(d.he...ght("").data("page")._trigger("hide", ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function using JQuery that loads data (in the case below into an un-ordered list):

```
function load_list(page_num) {
    $.get('location_of_output_script.php?page=' + page_num, function (data) {
        $('#add_html_to_me > li.click_to_see_more').remove();
        $('#add_html_to_me').append(data);
    });
}
```

Your page would need some element (an un-ordered list in this case) to which the new items would be appended:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul id="add_html_to_me"></ul>
</div>
```

Your output script ('location_of_output_script.php' in this example) could then return the desired number of results when a button is clicked (or perhaps when the user has scrolled close enough to the bottom of the list). Here is a sample of the output I am imagining:

```
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
<li>List item 4</li>
<li>List item 5</li>
<li class="click_to_see_more">Click Me To View More Rows</li>
```

SOME NOTEs:

- In my example you would load a button onto the end of each output from the server-side script that would be removed just before adding the next set of rows.
- You could replace the content of your list instead of adding to it by using the .html() function rather than .append().
- You may need to call .listview() on the <ul> tag to have JQuery Mobile style the new content in the list.
- If you want to add a spinner or some type of progress bar you can display it before you make the $.get call and then hide it inside of the success function of that call.

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing. I have the url in an anchor tag though and I'm essentially suppressing the default click behavior and calling the url with ajax to appent content to the list. I guess jquery mobile is doing some extra work and so progressive enhancement techniques may not work with jquery mobile?

Comment: I took out the anchor tag and used a span tag and it seems to work fine now. Thanks.